# No hint path defined for [mail] Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am trying to show my markdown email on view, but there's something wrong on my mail view, it shows like

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 112:
No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ppsb_new/core/resources/views/emails/tagihan.blade.php)
```

and my markdown mail view

```
@component('mail::message')
# TAGIHAN PEMBAYARAN

Berikut tagihan anda untuk pembayaran


@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
wut ?
@endcomponent

Gunakan kode tagihan tersebut untuk membayar tagihan.

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

and there's also vendor on my views who have their components.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You need to call the `markdown()` method in the `build()` method of your mailable - not the `view()` method. See the example below:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('view-to-mail');
}
```

Comment: please give more elaborate answers e.g. using examples.

Comment: @Ken check https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/27?autoplay=true

Comment: in which file you wrote that build method?

Comment: @RidIslam in your mailable class

Comment: If dont want to use pre-shiped  markdown then whats the solution

Comment: To customise the pre-shipped markdown components, run this command to publish the components to your file system: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`. Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-components

Answer (score 33):

To use Markdown mailable messages, you have to update the `build` method of your Mailable class and instead of `view()`, you have to use `markdown()`.

Like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.registered');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have your email views in ...views/mail, that is how you can specify it:

```
app('view')->addNamespace('mail', resource_path('views') . '/mail');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a View not found issue with laravel mail. After trying the accepted answer and it doesn't work, check yourtemplate.blade.php markdown file and ensure you are not closing `@endcomponent` twice without a opening `@component`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then used this syntax and worked as a charm

```php
@component('mail.html.message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail.html.button', ['url' => config('app.url')])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}

@endcomponent
```

Where my folder structure `views/mail/html` for markdown messages.

and my `App\Mail\NewEmail.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.new-message'); // -> pointing to views/mail/new-message.blade.php containing above message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use markdown in php blade file, then call view by markdown()
Or if you want to call blade file by view(), remove markdown syntax from blade file and use plane html.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a custom email view template, like this:

```
You received a message from : {{ $name }}

<p>
Name: {{ $name }}
</p>

<p>
Email: {{ $email }}
</p>

<p>
Message: {{ $user_message }}
</p>
```

Answer (score -4):

I used caffeinated/modules for laravel5.2.

If you are similar to me you can run this:

```
php artisan module:list
```

```
+------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+
| #    | Name  | Slug  | Description                         | Status   |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+
| 9001 | Frame | Frame | this is a basic frame for both web. | Disabled |
| 9001 | Index | Index | this is web default index           | Enabled  |
| 9001 | Admin | Admin | This is admin of meixin project     | Enabled  |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------+
```

All right, you can see the disabled option.

```
php artisan module:enable Frame
```

Module is already enabled.

That's all, hope this helps.

Comment: I know this didn't answer the question, but this solved my problem and I can't thank you enough.