# Laravel 5.4 No hint path defined for [mail]

Tags: php, laravel

When a user is made by an admin the following code is triggered:

usersController.php:

```
User::sendWelcomeEmail($user);
```

User.php:

```
 public static function sendWelcomeEmail($user)
{
  // Generate a new reset password token
  $token = app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($user);

  // Send email
  Mail::send('emails.registered', ['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('hello@vitaleassets.nl', 'Vitale Assets');
    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Welkom bij Vitale Assets');
  });
}
```

Registered.php:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.registered');
}
```

Registered.blade.php:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Welkom bij {{ config('app.name') }}

Wat leuk dat u gebruik gaat maken van onze applicatie! 
Voordat u verder kan moet u eerst uw wachtwoord instellen. 

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Stel wachtwoord in
@endcomponent

Bedankt,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

The difference between this question to [No hint path defined for [mail] Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289310/no-hint-path-defined-for-mail-laravel-5-4) is that I'm already using the markdown method and I'm still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you configured a mailable, but you're not using it? You're just sending using the Mail::send method?

Comment: hi @Djoezz diid you resolve your issue i am getting same issue can you help me?