# what does the :: (resolution scope operator) in laravel view helper?

Tags: php, laravel

I've seen this code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42289310/7551147)

```
@component('mail::message')
```

and i don't have any idea what does this `::` (resolution scope) do in laravel's view helper.

can anybody tell me what is this syntax in laravel view helper function?

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination of Blade components and Markdown syntax which allow you to easily construct mail messages.

Have a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#markdown-mailables) "Writing Markdown Messages"

Answer (score 1):

It's used for path resolution when rendering views. The portion before `::` serves as a namespace to a resource directory.

`::` is a delimiter defined by the constant `HINT_PATH_DELIMITER` in [ViewFinderInterface](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/View/ViewFinderInterface.php).

Using `mail::message` as an example, Laravel will search for a `message.blade.php` file in `resources/views/vendor/mail`.