# No hint path defined for [mail] - problem with send email in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8:

I have this code:

```
$mailTitle = "Masz wiadomość ze strony " . env('APP_NAME');
        $message = "
        <b>Dane wiadomości:</b> $dateTime [IP: $ip]<br/>
        <b>Tytuł wiadomości:</b> $title<br/>
        <b>Imię:</b> $userName<br/>
        <b>Adres email:</b> $userEmail<br/>
        <b>Wiadomość:</b> $txt<br/>";

        $data['slot']= $message;
        $data['adminEmail']= $adminEmail;
        $data['title']= $mailTitle;
        $data['user']= $userEmail;
        Mail::send('vendor.mail.html.message', $data, function($message) use($data) {
            $message->to($data['adminEmail']);
            $message->subject($data['title']);
            $message->replyTo($data['user']);
            $message->from($data['user']);
        });
```

When I run this code I have error:

```
No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: /var/www/vanessa/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289310/no-hint-path-defined-for-mail-laravel-5-4)

Comment: I use oryginal Laravel tempate (from Laravel Login/Registration mail).

Comment: your's url is from Laravel 5.4 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have blade in this path "vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php"
you need to make a blade and set in it your mail message

Comment: you use markdown or view ?  i think you use markdown

Comment: so   If you are using markdown in your template, you need to use the ->markdown() method rather than the ->view() method on your MailMessage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724118/laravel-5-4-how-to-customize-notification-email-layout

Comment: How can i do it?