# How to send an email in Laravel using the mail class? Can't get the sender email address

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a contact form and I want to retrieve the sender email address from the `request()` however I running into a few problems when I fill in the contact form and send, the email does not appear in mailtrap everything is configured correctly. I managed to get it working by sending an email to the recipient by doing `Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($data));` but I want to get the the sender email address.

I tried doing this but nothing happened no errors or email were produced, and the data is outputting in the array correctly. So I'm bit confused.

```
    public function store(){
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'number' => 'sometimes|nullable',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        Mail::send(new ContactFormMail($data), ['data' => $data],
            function ($message) use ($data)
            {
                $message
                    ->from($data['email'])
                    ->to('test@test.com');
            });

        return redirect('contact-us')->with('message', 'Thanks for your message. We\'ll be in touch.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used to retrieve the sender email.

        `Mail::send('Frontend::emails.contact.contact-form', ['data' => $data],
            function ($message) use ($data)
            {
                $message
                    ->from($data['email'])
                    ->to('test@test.com');
            });`

However this led to another issue No hint path defined for [mail]. This issue is to do with @component('mail::message') in the email blade so remove this and change the email blade to html which you can copy from the html source in mailtrap. Basically treat the markdown as HTML since it trying to reference a markdown class.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->from($this->data['email'])
                ->view('emails.your-email-view');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#configuring-the-sender

I hope this helps.

UPDATE:
Since you have `No hint path defined for [mail]`, then the problem must be that this is a markdown and you must call `->markdown('path-to-template')`, instead of `->view`.

This is a common question on stackoverflow: [No hint path defined for [mail] Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289310/no-hint-path-defined-for-mail-laravel-5-4)

Comment: I want use the ```$data['email']``` as the from email address I tried doing this ```Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($data))->from($data['email']);``` but get a call to a member function from() on null

Comment: This happens from your mailable. In your case the ContactFormMail. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried implementing that solution but it didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: Could you please show me the ContactFormMail class and how do you call it?

Comment: So this is my build function
`    public function build()
    {
//        return $this->markdown('emails.contact.contact-form');
        return $this->from($this->data['email'])
            ->view('emails.contact.contact-form');
    } `

How ever I get an error when I submit No hint path defined for [mail].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215441/discussion-between-nikolay-traykov-and-brandonk).