# Laravel 9 error "No hint path defined for [mail]."

Tags: php, laravel, email, markdown, laravel-artisan

At first when I try to create mail with artisan command

```
php artisan make:mail invoice -m
```

everything works fine, only when I run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

I don't know why suddenly I got this error when displaying the markdown view with routes.

Below is the route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('mail.invoice');
});
```

the mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Invoice extends Mailable
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public function __construct()
  {
    //
  }

  public function build()
  {
    return $this->from('ketaksaan@hotel.com')
      ->subject('Invoice Pemesanan Kamar Ketaksaan Hotel')
      ->markdown('mail.invoice');
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No hint path defined for \[mail\] Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289310/no-hint-path-defined-for-mail-laravel-5-4)